# Android Studio integration with GitHub failing to upload project files apart from MainActivity.java

Tags: android, github, version-control

I have recently created a new Android application and have used its VCS to integrate with GitHub. My problem is that although the integration appears to work, the only file in my Android application that has been saved to GitHub is MainActivity.java. I have tried to add files into GitHub but via the Website but this fails as there are too many files and it doesnt allow Folders to be added.
Has anyone else had this issue?

It's frustrating as when I make changes to MainActivity.java it gets saved and committed/pushed okay but the VCS in Android just doesn't see the other files I have changed such as the content_main.xml which I changed to see if it would then be added to GH.

I cannot seee how to add files within Android Studio to GH via VCS. Does anyone have any pointers where I may start? Thanks!

NB I have had a look through existing questions but none address my issue as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my shame once I checked Xiaomis suggestion I could see that my git was pointing to a directory lower than my /app directory. I tried to change in in my GitHub shell but was unable to do this as GitHub Desktop shell didn't recognise the new directory.

To fix my muddle I deleted my original repo and delted the .gitignore file and other git files from my Android project folder. I then opened Android Studio and went through the process of creating a new repo from there, circumventing GitHub entirely. This worked and enabled me to select my /app directory as the Git root. 
Thanks go to Xiaomi who's suggestion made me notice that git was looking at the wrong root. Live and learn!

Answer (score 1):

Usually when you start a new project, Go on VCS -> Enable Version Controle Integration.

Then you should have the Version Control accessible on the Bottom Left of the IDE.

In the tab Local Changes, you will see Default and Unversioned Files.

Just take files from Unversioned Files to Default to start to track them.

Comment: Thanks Xiaomi, I tried that and it appears that my Git was looking in a directory lower than I wanted, so It was only picking up that one file... I have tried to change the git root but I couldn't get it to work. I think I need to start again.